# How to change query type for drag and drop action in SQLDeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQLDeveloper there is a feature which generates query when you drag and drop table from connection browser to worksheet. There is a window which asks if one want select, update or delete query to be generated. I've marked once select and checked the box to not ask again. Now when I drag and drop I got always select without pop-up window.
How can I change query that is generated (I need insert not select) without reinstalling SQLDeveloper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go into the preferences. Database page. Then on 'Drag and Drop.'

[image: Set it back to Prompt or pick your new poison.]

Comment: No worries. I leave mine at prompt FWIW. 9x out of 10 I want it to build a SELECT w/JOINS but that 10th time it's a drag to go back to preferences.